# ID for rhandsontable inside modal in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, rhandsontable, showmodaldialog

My goal is to display an (conditional) editable rhandsontable inside a modal by clicking an actionbutton. Creating and displaying the table worked fine, however I'm struggling on how to properly assign an ID in the ui for the table in order to recognize user changes.

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('openModal', "Open Modal")
  # rHandsontableOutput("DataEditor") # doesn't work
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$openModal, {
    irrelevant_condition <- FALSE # include that rhandsontable doesn't have to appear always
    if (irrelevant_condition == TRUE) {
      return(showModal(modalDialog("Choose some variables to display first")))
    } else {
      # display rhandsontable if user made a valid choice
      showModal(modalDialog(  
        updDataEditor()
      ))
    }
  })
  
  updDataEditor <- function() {
    output$DataEditor <- renderRHandsontable({
      # in real app some conditional calculations leading to a DF called 'current.DF'
      # why function?: in real app with variation, depending on some inputs the user chose
      current.DF <- data.frame(Name = c("Name1", "Name2"), value1 = c(0,0), value2=c(0,0)) # example df
      rhandsontable(current.DF) 
    })
  }
    
  observeEvent(input$DataEditor, {
    # Here's the problem
    # won't get called when DataEditor is modified by the user
    browser() 
    return()
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('openModal', "Open Modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  current.DF <- reactive(
    data.frame(Name = c("Name1", "Name2"), value1 = c(0,0), value2=c(0,0))
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$openModal, {
    irrelevant_condition <- FALSE # include that rhandsontable doesn't have to appear always
    if (irrelevant_condition == TRUE) {
      return(showModal(modalDialog("Choose some variables to display first")))
    } else {
      # display rhandsontable if user made a valid choice
      showModal(modalDialog(  
        rHandsontableOutput("DataEditor")
      ))
    }
  })
  
  output$DataEditor <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(current.DF()) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$DataEditor, {
    print(input$DataEditor$changes)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Is it what you want? For the dataframe which can change I would use a reactive value. If only some cells are changed you can use the `set_data` function, better.

---

***EDIT*** Solving the problem raised in the comments:

```
  output$DataEditor <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(current.DF()) %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(
      "function(el){var hot = this.hot; setTimeout(function(){hot.render();}, 1000)}"
    )
  })
```

Comment: This works, thank you :) Guessed there should be a simple solution but got stuck. Why would you recommend a reactive for the dataframe?

Comment: There is one problem with this solution: If the modal gets opened, closed and then opened again the table doesn't display properly

Comment: @chrisgeo Indeed, strange. See my edit.